# glGenBuffers access violation exception

Tags: c++, glew, glfw

I'm using `GLFW` and `GLEW`.
But during initialization of my object `glGenBuffers` throws an exception

```
void Character::init2D(glm::vec3 top, glm::vec3 bottom_left, glm::vec3 bottom_right)
{
    glm::vec3 Vertices[3];
    Vertices[0] = bottom_left;
    Vertices[1] = top;
    Vertices[2] = bottom_right;

    this->top = top;
    this->left_front = bottom_left;
    this->right_front = bottom_right;

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO); //throws an exception 0xC0000005: Access violation
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    CompileShaders(shaderProgram, "vertex.shader", "fragment.shader");
}
```

I declare my class `Character` like this

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\type_ptr.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")

class Character
{
private:
    glm::vec3   top, 
                left_front, 
                right_front, 
                left_back, 
                right_back;
    GLuint VBO;
    GLuint shaderProgram;
public:
    Character();
    void init2D(glm::vec3 top, 
                glm::vec3 bottom_left, 
                glm::vec3 bottom_right);
    void draw();
    void move();
    void action();
    ~Character() {};
};
```

And my `main.cpp` looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include "character.h"
#define WIDTH 600
#define HEIGHT 600

using namespace std;

Character simple;

void render()
{
    simple.draw();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GLFWwindow *window;

    if (!glewInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Imensia", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) { glfwTerminate(); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    glm::vec3 left(-0.5, 0, 0);
    glm::vec3 top(0, 0.5, 0);
    glm::vec3 right(0.5, 0, 0);

    simple.init2D(top, left, right);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT); 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        render();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
};
```

Is it problem with initialization or what?
In `properties` of the project I set `include` and `library` directories...

Comment: Are you sure to have `VBO` initialized correctly (whatever this is)?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but GLEW calls to functions that are unsupported by the hardware will result in access violations, so you have to check for support at runtime.

Comment: Also make sure that you've initialised GLEW and set up an opengl context.

Answer (score 7):

Glew initialization should be done after the windows/opengl context is created.

For the given code, `glewInit` could be moved right below the `glfwCreateWindow`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GLFWwindow *window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Imensia", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) { glfwTerminate(); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    if (!glewInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    :
    :
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keugyeols approach has helped me fix the problem. If you follow the tutorial mentioned on glfws docs, this may help you.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if(!glewInit()){
        return 0;
    }
    /*your code
     *
     */
}
```